# Is there a way to define Wildcard Route in ZendFramework to route whole Module to Another?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

Is there a way to define Wildcard Route in ZendFramework to route whole Module to Another ??

e.g. I want

http://website.com/ **people** / **controller** / **action** / to be routed to

http://website.com/ **friend** / **controller** / **action** /

I can do this by .htaccess but is there a way to do it in route other than the following 3 sentences together ?

```
$router->addRoute('friend',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('people/:controller/:action',
                array("module"=>'friend')));

$router->addRoute('friend2',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('people/:controller',
                array("module"=>'friend',"action"=>"index")));      

$router->addRoute('friend3',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('people/',
                array("module"=>'friend',"action"=>"index","controller"=>"index")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by creating plugin

```
class My_Routing extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown($request)
    {
       $m = $this->_request->getModuleName();
       if($m == 'people') 
       {
         $this->_request->setModuleName('friends');
       }    
    }
}
```